# How to display image after using setRGB(x,y,0) in Java?

Tags: java, image, colors, pixel, rgb

```
for(int x=0;x<20;x++)
{
    for(int y=0;y<20;y++)
    {
       img.setRGB(x, y,0);
    }
}
```

I'm trying to convert all pixels in a 20*20 region to black colour. But this is not working with the above code. Do i need to add anything more?

Comment: What is the image type and what do you mean by *"How to display image"* ?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  Hot=link to a suitable image or generate one in code.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
int rgb=new Color(0,0,0).getRGB(); // i believe rgb for black is 0,0,0 but cross check


for(int x=0;x<20;x++){

for(int y=0;y<20;y++){

              img.setRGB(x, y,rgb);

              }
         }
```